# Android Studio SQLite query from the user including " ' "

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a dictionary app where user needs to input in an editText and click the translate button to display the result. It works perfectly but whenever a user inputs a query including ' (e.g. Baker's), I get SQLite error as follows:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: select * from words where vocab = 'Baker's'

```
binding.transcribe.setOnClickListener {
        
        val Word = binding.editText.text.toString()

        val Answer = dbHelp.getAnswer(Word)
        binding.transcribedVersion.text = Answer
    }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: try to escape the single quote by replacing it with ''. So 'Baker's' should be 'Baker''s'

Answer (score 0):

you can use double quote instead of single quote, like this:
`select * from words where vocab = 'Baker''s'`

Comment: I receive the query from the user so I cannot manually modify the structure of their input

Comment: @Aschente you can process the user input before passing it to the query. You get the text from the input field modify it however you want (like adding an extra quote where you detect a quote) and pass it to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use selection args:

```
select * from words where vocab = ?
```

that you can bind later using your value

```
val selectionArgs = arrayOf("Baker's")
```

#### update

If you are using `rawQuery` it would be like

```
db.rawQuery("select * from words where vocab = ?", arrayOf("Baker's"))
```

Comment: I have a similar code returning query that is asked to the user:
val cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from words where vocab = '${query}'", null, null)
but this is a dictionary with over 500k entries so entering the data including ' would prove difficult and even if that's the case when the user enters a word that is nonexistent in the db like "Aardvark's", the app crushes again